# Symlinks for web pages

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, web-server, symlink

I have my web server set up running multiple sites and host them all in `~/sites/`, outside apache document root (`~/www`), as follows:

```
+-~/
  +-sites/
    +-project1/
    | +-system/
    | +-application/
    | +-public_html/
    |   +-images/
    |   +-css/
    |   +-index.php
    +-project2/
    | +-system/
    | +-application/
    | +-public_html/
    |   +-images/
    |   +-css/
    |   +-index.php
```

I order to make sites available via the web I create a symlink in `~/www/`, as below:

```
+-~/
  +-www/
    +-project1 -> ~/sites/project1/public_html
    +-project2 -> ~/sites/project2/public_html
```

With this set up I end up with `domain.com/project1` and `domain.com/project2` pointing to my `~/sites/projectx` directories and can easily change where they point to take a site offline.

**The problem I'm having is how to host** `domain.com` **outside the document root;** I can't set up a symlink like the others because the symlink would have to be `~/www/` which obviously can't be used.

TLDR; I want to set up `~/sites/domain/public_html` to be served when `domain.com` is requested.

Comment: how to create a symlink? maybe `ln /from/here/ /to/here/`?

Answer (score 2):

Create it as a virtualhost. I do this all the time. My documentroot is /var/www/HTML but I host some sites under /home/

Comment: I can't create a virtual host, I'm on a shared server and do not have access to `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a virtualhost.
Here you have an example of this:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/httpd/sites/site1"
ServerName   site1.com

<Directory "/home/httpd/sites/site1">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Remember include the file in your httpd.conf